# Android ListViews that do not take a whole activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Im new to the android programming language and am trying to get an android application that has a ListView as half the screen and a ScrollView as the other half. Then I was trying to get it so when an item is clicked in the ListView the information in the item would be displayed as a TextView in the ScrollView. In the ListView there are 2 TextViews.

is this possible?

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution:

Put the `ListView` and `ScrollView` in a horizontal `LinearLayout`, give them both `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. If you want the screen to be split vertically instead, use a vertical `LinearLayout` and give the two views `android:layout_height="0dp"` instead of `layout_width`.

A more complicated, but better solution is to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).